# Codeigniter HMVC on wamp server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter 2.1.4 project which uses HMVC pattern. The project runs smoothly remotely but running it locally on wamp server seems to have some problems with the aforementioned pattern because when I try to access any page

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

error pops up. What might be the reason for this?
**.htaccess** file on local server is as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|install|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but on live server its different. Below is the structure of my application

[image]

Comment: File name might be an issue. On remote server you have linux file system and on you local machine you have windows. Make sure you file names in correct form. Please provide some more details as well.

Comment: can you share your htaccess ?

Comment: Please provide more detail for better understand your question...@lil

Comment: Please provide url which you are trying to access and make sure apache's mod rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola the rewrite mod is enabled and I have also tried capitalizing file names  but the error persists

Comment: Try with sitename.com/index.php/skills.php if this is also showing a 404 error then check with class name inside the code. The class name should match the File name.

Comment: The latest version of HMVC s only for codeigniter 3 v and above https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads?tab=branches